# Let a table inside of fragment, the error is that on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is code:

```
public class Persion1_fragment extends Fragment{
    Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.mContext = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TableFixHeaders tableFixHeaders = (TableFixHeaders)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table);
        String [][] str=new String[][] {
                {
                        "Header 1",
                        "Header 2",
                        "Header 3",
                        "Header 4",
                        "Header 5",
                        "Header 6" },
        };

        MatrixTableAdapter<String> matrixTableAdapter = new MatrixTableAdapter<String>(this.mContext,str);
        tableFixHeaders.setAdapter(matrixTableAdapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.persion3, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here is error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.inqbarna.tablefixheaders.TableFixHeaders.setAdapter(com.inqbarna.tablefixheaders.adapters.TableAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

and I'm using the open source edition of TableFixHeaders.
I really look forward of help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TableFixHeaders tableFixHeaders = (TableFixHeaders)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table);
```

This line has some problem and so, tableFixHeaders is actually null.

You should inflate the View first and find child views from the inflated View.

Try this code in your onCreateView().

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.persion3, container, false);
TableFixHeaders tableFixHeaders = (TableFixHeaders)view.findViewById(R.id.table);
String [][] str=new String[][] {
        {
                "Header 1",
                "Header 2",
                "Header 3",
                "Header 4",
                "Header 5",
                "Header 6" },
};

MatrixTableAdapter<String> matrixTableAdapter = new MatrixTableAdapter<String>(this.mContext,str);
tableFixHeaders.setAdapter(matrixTableAdapter);
return view;
```

Comment: Just for clarification: the exception occurred because you selected the table from the wrong view. Doing `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table)`, you asked the parent activity to give you the table (which it hasn't since it is in your fragment) and it's returning `null`. From this point I guess that you know why your app crashes. @Suhyeon posted the solution, so give it a try and don't forget to accept his answer if it worked (and I'm sure that it will).